# Integrating React Native with existing Android Apps

Tags: android, react-native

I followed both this tutorials [tutorial 1](https://blog.usejournal.com/integrating-react-native-with-existing-android-apps-efficiently-3b39f2e061bd) and [tutorial 2](https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps#:%7E:text=The%20keys%20to%20integrating%20React,React%20Native%20components%20in%20JavaScript.&text=Start%20the%20React%20Native%20server%20and%20run%20your%20native%20application.)

I added all dependencies in build.gradle file.

and I also added this

```
//(MainApplication) Manual ReactPackage Setup here...
 apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform- 
 android/native_modules.gradle");
 applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

But , I have the following error

[image: error pic]

How can I solve this ?

Comment: `PackageList` should be generated after you start the build. If it is configured correctly the error should disappear after you start building the app

Comment: I build the app but also the error occurs.